# Validation rule for age in years, months and days

Tags: apex, formula, validation, validation-rule, contact

I want to ensure that the age of my contacts be less than 20 years, 5 months and 15 days.

Till 20 years and 5 months, I am able to write the rule by multiplying the years with 12 and adding the months to it and then comparing. But I am unable to figure out how to check for 15 days in the validation rule.

How can this be achieved keeping the leap years in consideration ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

In a validation rule I think you will be unable to account for leap years. In this case I would just convert your 20 years, 5 months and 15 days to days.

```
Birthdate > (TODAY() - 7467)
```

If you are building this out in Apex you might be able to use `isLeapYear()` to help you but it would be quite messy.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm

Comment: Based on your answer, I wrote

Birthday < ADDMONTHS((TODAY()-29),-251) and it appears to be working fine despite the leap years in between